# i want to get image from imageview?

Tags: android

i have this xml and i want to  get image  from thisi mageview.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/result_resultView"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pic_boarder"
        android:maxHeight="100dip" />
```

while in Activity

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_resultView);
```

view .setImageResource(R.drawable.m_2);

i want to get m_2 through the imageview having id result_resultView.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getDrawable()` method which returns an [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). This Drawable is an instance of [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) which allows you to get the Bitmap.

```
Bitmap image = null;
if(imageView.getDrawable() instanceof BitMapDrawable){
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    image = drawable.getBitmap();
}
```

**edit**
I suggest to better check if it it reallay an instance of BitmapDrawable before casting.